# How to change alignment of certain inline-block elements within a DIV?

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

I'm trying to achieve that one inline-block elements, would be aligned left and the other one would be aligned right, without changing their display type.

I would like to get a CSS version, otherwise I could live with a jQuery approach as well.

What I mean, I just wanted to show the first two buttons aligned on the left side, the third button on the right side.

[jsBin not working example](http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/8/edit)

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div style="background-color: lightblue; width: 600px;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; height:20px; background-color: red; margin: 5px 3px;float: left;">
              Button
            </span>

            <span style="display: inline-block; height:20px; background-color: red; margin: 5px 3px; float:right;">
              Button right
            </span>
        </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>where did the background of the header cell go? the background is still there if the elements do not float.</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please include the problem code in your post as well as the jsbin link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle)

Comment: what do you mean by align left? whether to move whole element to left or text inside it.

Comment: @SatyaTeja I meant align right, i'll correct the post

Comment: But, these are inline with no width set.  How can you have alternating alignment on sequential inline elements?  It is not clear what you want the result to look like.

Comment: @Toskan Please take a look, I have aligned your button on the right. Tell me if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: @jfriend00 have a look at ilia's solution

Comment: I can't evaluate a solution when I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  Your question is not clear.  Maybe some people can guess what you want.  I cannot.  Your question says  one left, next one right.  In Ilia's, I see two left and one right, not what I thought you asked for.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm sure it already occurred to you as well, that when you spent quite a bunch of time on something, that it seems very obvious to you. No need to closevote the question.

Comment: I didn't close vote, but I did downvote the question because it's still not clear what you want.  I was giving you an opportunity to clarify your question.  What is the desired output layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set property `float:right` to your `span` element.

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/10/edit)

In the second example you provided in the comment, the one with the table, you simply had that problem, because you didn't set the style to the `th` tag but to the `div` tag. If you set the property of `background-color` and `width` to the `th` tag, you will get what you want.

[Another Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MwZc8/)

Comment: this is absolutely correct. This is just what I want it to look like. The problem was float in the first place though. I used float in my scenario and this is what happened: http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/11/edit I thought it would always happen, it seems only to happen within tables though. Any ideas?

Comment: add this point i want to refer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407541/white-space-nowrap-vs-white-space-normal-why-is-the-effect-on-floating-element

Comment: @Toskan You just did. :) People will read our comments and follow your link if they are interested!

Answer (score 1):

`<span>`'s are natively inline-block elements -- so that declaration is unnecessary. You could also apply your CSS to the `<th>` element rather than wrapping everything in that `<div>`, and utilize `:last-child`. Technically, you could get rid of the `float:left`, but it would cause additional CSS to vertically align the buttons.

```
CSS
    th { background-color:lightblue; width:600px; }
    th span { background-color:red; float:left; height:20px; margin:5px 3px; }
    th span:last-child { float:right }

HTML
    <th>
        <span>Button</span>
        <span>Button</span>
        <span>Button right</span>
    </th>
```