# White-space: nowrap vs white-space: normal why is the effect on floating elements so big?

Tags: css, alignment

[Definition from w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) : 
**normal**  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary. This is default  Play it »
**nowrap**  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
 tag is encountered.

So why does it make so much difference in the looks of floated elements?

e.g. compare this:

[JsBin with white-space normal showing a nicely aligned layout](http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/22/edit)

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div style="background-color: lightblue; width: 600px; white-space: normal;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; height:20px; background-color: red; margin: 5px 3px;float: left;">
              Button
            </span>
            <span style="display: inline-block; height:20px; background-color: red; margin: 5px 3px;float: none;">
              Button
            </span>
            <span style="display: inline-block; height:20px; background-color: red; margin: 5px 3px; float:right;">
              Button right
            </span>
            <div style="clear: both" />
        </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>note: white-space is normal here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[White this where white-space: nowrap is used](http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/23/edit)

it's the same code as above, only this time white-space: nowrap;

someone got a clue?
**[EDIT]**
as people commented they can see no difference, I upload a screenshot of the problematic white-space: nowrap
I'm on firefox 10.0.4
[image: white-space: nowrap results in 2 rows in firefox 10.0.4]

Comment: Why are you doing `white-space: nowrap;` in the first place? It works without it: [little link](http://jsbin.com/ibifoq/28/edit).

Comment: I'm actually not seeing any difference here.  Also, you don't have any text that would wrap in the first place.  You shouldn't see a difference unless you had text that would normally wrap to another line.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` is also crucial for using `text-overflow: ellipse`

Comment: @Scrimothy `text-overflow: ellipse;` on an element with floated `div`s inside it? I don't get the point.

Comment: @Abody97, in this case you wouldn't need it.  I just threw that in because the overall question was about the differences between `white-space:nowrap` and `white-space:normal`.

Comment: @Scrimothy : That's exactly what I thought! there should be no difference. But: in firefox it displays as 2 rows. I run on firefox 10.0.4 esr. My company does not let me display it in different browsers

Comment: @Abody97 obviously I was having different problems than you saw :-) basically I want to be able to switch between wrapping of buttons and not wrapping buttons. But work is in progress, and as it seems, that must be a different question.

Comment: @Toskan this is a bug in firefox and its not been fixed yet(ff38)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I somewhat retract my initial comment above.  If you have `div`s `float`ed inside a `white-space: nowrap div` and your parent `div` has a fixed width, you would get what I mentioned in my comment.  However if your children were either `inline` or `inline-block` then those child `div`s would just keep going beyond the right side `overflow` (just like what inline text would do).  Normally, when you `float: left` the children reach the end of the parent and wrap onto another line.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/e6rbk/1/) illustration.

Answer (score 4):

`white-space: nowrap` and `float: right` is known "bug" of Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725

I ask question about right aligned triangle in menu: [Align to right "left triangle" in menu element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006130/align-to-right-left-triangle-in-menu-element). I prepare fix that uses `padding-right`, negative `margin-left` and `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add this http://jsfiddle.net/cstephe/tNHLL/ shows how order also effects this in Firefox 10 atleast I'll check this when i get home on a more current version.

EDIT:This is how it looks locally for me.

[image]

```
 <h2>float first: nowrap / Children: floating blocks</h2>
<div class="wrapper nowrap">
     <div class="inlineBlock floating"></div>
     <div class="inlineBlock floating float-right">r</div>
     <div class="inlineBlock">something</div>

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<h2>typical order: nowrap / Children: floating blocks</h2>
<div class="wrapper nowrap">
     <div class="inlineBlock floating"></div>

     <div class="inlineBlock">something</div>
    <div class="inlineBlock floating float-right">r</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to look the same in chrome 22 and firefox 10.

Comment: I'll test it out on my home pc but so far I,ve seen the difference in ff10 and mobile safari

Comment: it just looks the same to me in chrome  Version 22.0.1229.94 m and ff 10.0.9: what looks different for you? what do you actually mean?

Comment: this might be something specific to FF 10.0.10  I keep forgetting to check it from home.  I guess the one thing we might be able to get out of this is, if you see some behavior like this changing the order might do it for you,  however its a bad situation.